# How to add parachains to parity signer?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rpc

I'm setting up a metadata site for parachains. I have the github pages site working, and am currently adding parachains. I just have a few questions to make sure I do this properly.

For `rpc_endpoint` is there a list of rpc urls per parachain anywhere? Is it possible to add multiple rpcs to select from currently per chain?

For `owner` is that the name of the developer team?
For `repo` is that the teams github repo name?

I currently have for Acala this:

```
[[chains]]
name = "acala"
rpc_endpoint = "wss://"
color = "#645AFF"

[chains.github_release]
owner = "AcalaNetwork"
repo = "Acala"
genesis_hash = "0xfc41b9bd8ef8fe53d58c7ea67c794c7ec9a73daf05e6d54b14ff6342c99ba64c"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add multiple rpcs to select from currently per chain?

Yes, you can use `rpc_endpoints` setting to specify a list of urls.

> For owner is that the name of the developer team? For repo is that the teams github repo name?

Correct.